# Evitar crear PR en la UI de GitHub sin archivos modificados

Tags: github

tengo dos ramas en GitHub, las cuales la diferencia son algunos commits (son merge de una rama sobre la otra) pero no hay ningún archivo modificado.
Sería posible evitar crear PR sin archivos modificados en laUI de GitHub?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Please reopen your question in stackoverflow.com (root domain), this is Stack Overflow in Spanish.

Comment: gracias Ariel, pregunta modificada!